# Using jit decorator for a code that contains opening and closing of files

Tags: python, numba, jit

I have a program that uses Numba's @jit decorator in the nopython mode to output results in a considerable shorter time as compared to the non-Numba version. I now want to store some results at each loop to a .dat file in my program.

For a normal version, I would just use `open` but jit decorator does not support it.

So here is just a sample representative code to my actual code:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(x,y,z):
  max=10
  Time=0
  time_plot=[Time]
  X=[x]
  Y=[y]
  Tfile=f.open('T.dat')  
  while Time<max:
    T=np.empty(z-1)
    Time=Time+0.001
    for i in range(z):
      X.append(T)
      Y.append(T**2)
      Z.append(T**3)
      a=np.mean(X)+np.mean(Y)+np.mean(Z) 
      Tfile.write(str(a))
      Tfile.write('\n')
  Tfile.close()
```

This doesn't work due to:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'open' of type recursive(type(CPUDispatcher(<function f at 0x000001817D97C8B0>)))
```

What alternative do I have?

Comment: You can't use open from within Numba, an option would be to use the `objmode` context manager. But that will cost you performance. It's often best to simply separate concerns. Your code also doesn't make much sense, it contains for example an infinite loop.
https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/withobjmode.html

Comment: @RutgerKassies I corrected the code to make the loop finite.

Comment: Numba is not a general purpose JIT (as opposed to PyPy or Pyston for example). It does not support `open` or `write`. Besides this, string operations are pretty slow currently in Numba. `append` is not efficient in Numba (direct indexing is). Additionally, you recompute the mean over and over which is not efficient. Consider implementing a incremental sliding mean. Numba should be used only when the algorithm is optimized, not before (unless it require to rewrite a huge portion of the code which may not be reasonable).